# Subtract matrix of n,k dimensions from array of matrices of n,k dimensions

Tags: arrays, r, matrix, apply

If I have an array A

```
A <- array(0, c(4, 3, 5))
for(i in 1:5) {
  set.seed(i)
  A[, , i] <- matrix(rnorm(12), 4, 3)
}
```

and if I have matrix B

```
set.seed(6)
B <- matrix(rnorm(12), 4, 3)
```

The code to subtract B from the each matrix of the array A would be:

```
d<-array(0, c(4,3,5))
for(i in 1:5){
  d[,,i]<-A[,,i]-B
}
```

However, what would be the code to perform the same calculation using a function from "apply" family?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is what `sweep` is for.

```
sweep(A, 1:2, B)
```

Comment: Yet another powerful command with an utterly non-intuitive name (to non-statisticians)... I love R! Name is dissimilar to 'apply'.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe not very intuitive:

```
A[] <- apply(A, 3, `-`, B)
```

Comment: Tnx for valuable reply.
Please, tell me what we actually say to R to do while keeping the A[]?

Comment: It means to assign into the elements of `A` within the brackets. You may recall that when indexing, a missing dimension means "select all elements in that dimension", for example `mat[1, ]` means "select the 1st row and all columns of matrix `mat`". This convention also holds when doing single-dimensional indexing, so `[]` means "select all elements". What it does here is that it assigns into `A` _while keeping its dimensions intact_. This is necessary here because `apply` by itself will return a 2-dimensional structure, while we want a 3-dimensional result.

Answer (score 4):

Because you are looping on the last array dimension, you can simply do:

```
d <- A - as.vector(B)
```

and it will be much faster. It is the same idea as when you subtract a vector from a matrix: the vector is recycled so it is subtracted to each column.

Comment: I needed to loop over entire dimensions of the array. Maybe I introduced some misunderstanding because in the first post I wrote set.seed(5) giving numerical differences only for the last dimension of the array. However, I edited the post (e.g. set.seed(i)) and probably make what I am intended to do more intuitive and clear.
However, many thanks for reply!

Comment: @Newbie_R: I don't think you realize my answer is giving the same result as yours.

Comment: You are right! 
I obtained different results because I have checked your suggestion with a wrong matrix B...my fault.
Tnx